# Modify Solr search query text with some condition

Tags: asp.net, search, solr, ektron

I have integrated **Solr search** with my ektron site. And for search functionality I used **Search framework API**.
I am getting the search results as well. Now I want my search result to display in **some particluar order**. ie. the result item with target url that contains the search text should come first, followed by some other contents and so on.
I came to know that by **modifiying the query text** that passing to the **Solr** can return the desired  result. 
**eg :   title:testkeyword**

But I can't do the same with target url and and cant boost up items.
Do any know how to modify the query text to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Use dismax and edismax to get better results ,

http://wiki.solarium-project.org/index.php/V3:EDisMax_component

http://wiki.solarium-project.org/index.php/V2:DisMax_component

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
I am getting '400 Bad request' error from Solr. Can you help me in modelling the QueryText using the DisMax syntax

Comment: Yes , Sure , Send me the details

Comment: How should my QueryText looks like if my search text is 'foo'. When I use this EdisMAX or DisMax components in my queryText error occurs. And to use EdisMAX or DisMax query parser what should I do in the configuration file.